# "Connection for the USB device was unsuccesful" error in VMware

Tags: vmware

I cannot connect my USB device to guest OS when I use one of the USB ports on my machine.

VMware gives an error like:

> The connection for the USB device was unsuccessful. The device is currently in use.

However, when I use the other USB port, the device successfully connects to the guest OS. How can I fix it?

Comment: Is the first USB port 3.0 and the second 2.0? This seems to be a common problem